# React - why do I need to wrap functions called by useState in an anonymous function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance, react-hooks, anonymous-function

I have been taking a React performance training course and this code base is used as an example: https://github.com/stevekinney/wordman/blob/main/src/components/application.jsx#L10

When we call the function inside of `useState()` it is called on every re-render even though the actual value of `correctAnswer` does not change. If the function was large and complicated, this could cause a performance issue.

e.g.

```
const [correctAnswer, setCorrectAnswer] = useState(generateRandomColor());
```

To avoid this, I have to wrap it in an anonymous function or not invoke the function within the `useState` hook.

e.g.

```
const [correctAnswer, setCorrectAnswer] = useState(() => generateRandomColor());
const [correctAnswer, setCorrectAnswer] = useState(generateRandomColor);
```

Why is that? What is going on behind the scenes in JavaScript?

Answer (score 1):

When you call the function explicitly `generateRandomColor()`, the function is called on each render. The function is called because the wrapping function component is executed, and you manually execute the function (note the parentheses).

When you pass the function to `useState` without calling it (note the lack of parentheses), the `useEffect` would only execute it when initializing:

```
useState(generateRandomColor);
```

Pass an anonymous function is identical. You pass a function that you want the `useEffect` to call only on init.

Answer (score 1):

> What is going on behind the scenes in JavaScript?

It's not really anything to do with the *language*, it's just how React function components and `useState` work. Your function is called **every time** the component needs to render, but as you said, `useState` only uses the initial value you give it on the **first** render — after that, it completely ignores what you give it. But `useState(generateRandomColor())` means this:

- Run `generateRandomColor`, get its return value
- Pass that return value into `useState`

Since `useState` will ignore the passed value after the first render, that means the call to `generateRandomColor` is pointless on any render but the first.

That's why `useState` allows you to pass in a function instead: It will only call the function on the first render. So if the function doesn't have any parameters, you can do `useState(generateRandomColor);` to pass the function to `useState`, which will call it the first time and ignore it other times. (If the function needed parameters, then you'd need a wrapper function.)